# Can I merge the output negative of multiple LED drivers?

Tags: led-driver

I have a LED COB with 6 strips, 8 A DC constant each, fed by 6 LED drivers ([Meanwell HLG320H](https://www.meanwell.fr/ac-dc-single-output-led-driver-mix-mode-cv-cc-with-hlg--320h--42ab)).
They will be driven by the same 1-10 V dimming current.

Can I merge (put into contact) all 6 negative (-) output electrical contacts (8 A DC) or do I have to convey each of them separately? Why?

According to the LED driver terms, I'm wondering if I can connect multiple V- together; the goal is to make the cable set lighter.

I add that the COB has 6 separated strips, each with its + and - contacts.

Comment: What you are asking about is putting multiple power supplies in parallel.  As has been discussed here before, in general, you don't want to do this unless they are designed to be used that way.  I don't see anything to that effect in the data sheet you referenced.

Comment: Unless the OP is talking about only commoning one rail. I can't quite make it out from the question.

Comment: @DanSheppard Yes, that's another way to word the OP.

Comment: @SteveSh I'm not sure it's actually this, since the + won't be put in common, only the (-) (mass?).

Comment: Connecting multiple power supplies to a common ground is okay. However, I'm not sure how the dimming pins will behave in that condition. Could you check whether DIM- is connected to OUT- with a multimeter?

Comment: Note that "mass" is at best a very strange word for what you mean here in English. I believe you mean the "ground", "negative", or "return" wire, but it might be a good idea to clarify that.

Comment: @JonathanS. [The datasheet](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/HLG-320H/HLG-320H-spec.pdf) (for anyone else, this is an English version of the datasheet, also) specifically says (page 4) "Do NOT connect DIM- to -V", which I believe answers that.

Comment: @Hearth Indeed. I updated to negative. I'm not trying to connect DIM- to V-, but multiple V- together, if possible

Comment: @Soleil Right, I understood that's what you meant--my comment about DIM- and -V is in reply to Jonathan's comment asking whether the two are internally connected--a warning in the datasheet telling you not to connect them externally would imply that they are not internally connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean here, but a couple possible things (drawing just three of your strips and power supplies for brevity):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9P3oy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is fine, as long as the wire marked "high current" is fine with carrying six times the current of a single LED driver. Just use a thicker wire for the negative side. You can also flip this around and use a single wire for the positive side if you use six separate wires for the negative side, though that would be an unusual configuration that would likely leave anyone repairing it in the future wondering why you did that.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZBFNz.png)</sup>

This is fine with wires that can't handle the full six times current, and is recommended for keeping the devices at the same potential, if they're not connected elsewhere. The connection can also be on the driver end of the wires if that's easier. Again, you can also do this on the positive side, as long as it's only one side, but it would be... non-idiomatic, for lack of a better word.

---

And finally, it looks like this *isn't* what you mean, but just to be clear:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbHZS3.png)</sup>

This is *not* fine, even if you have high current wires on both positive and negative. Most power supplies are not designed to be put in parallel like this, and will not work (perhaps even damage each other or themselves) if you try. It is *possible* to design power supplies for paralleling like this, but it takes special design and, in most cases, additional communication between the supplies to ensure they're working together instead of one doing all the work and the others doing none.

Not to mention, this would do nothing to ensure that all your LED strips get the same current, so one LED strip could well take all the current, overheat, and die, followed by another one taking all the current, overheating, and dying, and so on.

Comment: In any case this seems to be a bad or not interesting idea. I edited the OP with the goal, which is to have less many cables. According to your answer, if I merge the six V- together I should also increase the cable section accordingly (for 48A, so at least 4.8mm^2), instead of having at least 1mm^2 (for 1mm^2 per 10A) for each.

Comment: @Soleil Depends on how much current you can put through your wires. One 4.8 mm² cable is probably still smaller than six 1 mm² ones. And a 1 mm² wire is probably thicker than it strictly needs to be, besides.